# IdentityServer4: Multiple Instances of a WinForm client with client credentials - Token question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, identityserver4

I have a WinForm App and an API which I secure with IdentityServer4. The client setup in IS4 is as follows, since there are no individual credentials, and only this application itself should have general access to the API.

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ClientApp",
        // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

    // secret for authentication
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    // scopes that client has access to
    AllowedScopes = { "APIOne" }
}
```

This works well so far, but I have a question about multiple instances of the WinForm app. Do all clients receive the same token? Because there are no individual credentials, only a client secret.

If I take a look into the tokens with https://jwt.io/ I see that they are different, but only the "exp" field, rest seems to be the same.

Comment: Each instance of the application should have a unique ClientId. Because the ClientId and Secret are the credentials of the client in a client credentials flow.

Comment: You can pass the client id as [documented](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#creating-the-client): `await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest { });`

Comment: Now I am a bit confused: The configuration in the initial post is from IS4 and the WinForm app is called "ClientApp". If I have n users of the software "ClientApp" out there, with no individual user crendentials, do you say I need to configure n Clients which I don't know? I thought that would be the reason to have ClientCredentials to allow one type of Client to authenticate.

Comment: Client credentials are used for machine to machine communication, when no users are involved. ClientId identifies the (instance of the) client, not type of client. You do know the client, because you are using a serial number. But you can't use it in the client credentials flow because you can't pass it. One option is to use the serial number as clientid (which should be configurable) or create a [custom grant](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html#refextensiongrants) that requires an additional parameter: serial number.

Comment: This new grant type would be an extension of the client credentials grant type. IMO you should still use different clientid's, because what's the use of credentials when everybody is using the same? It also gives you more control over the clients, e.g. when you want to revoke access.

Comment: The "use" is that only MY app can access the API and no other "client" like Postman, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. Any 'client' that knows the clientid and secret can 'impersonate' your app and request an access token. Any (postman) client using the access token can access your api, regardless of which grant type was used. When the client is running in an environment that is not under your control, can you be sure that it can keep a secret?

Answer (score 0):

> This works well so far, but I have a question about multiple instances of the WinForm app. Do all clients receive the same token?

No, in general they have not. But do note: if they would receive the same token it shouldn't matter.

The `exp` field is most likely "always" different, because it depends on the time it has been created, and therefor your token will not likely to be the same.

But, again; the token is most likely signed (or even encrypted). This is basically your safe-guard that the token is valid. Even if the tokens are equal, it should not matter. This means, the server for example, shouldn't expect the token to be unique.

---

#### Having said that; there is a catch.

It seems, that you now have a couple application which log's in with the same api key and secret.

I would suggest to add something, like a `client id` just to be able to identify the different clients. It would also make your token unique.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which I will take as "it doesnt really matter" if I understood correctly.
The idea with a `client id` is something I can do because each client has a unique serial number. But where and how to I add it to the token request?

Comment: Yes, good question, it might be harder than I thought. And, yes; the "doesn't matter" part still stands.

Comment: Basically, since youre using identity server you would be able to customize it through headers.

Comment: @Igotcha: basically, if you want to do it, it's going to take quite some effort and customization. You can find some of it around on the web, but if you don't need it, you don't have to. And, you could also use different way's to identify the actual client, e.g.: by passing an http header with each request.